# Can not Allow the decimal value inside input field using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-pattern

I need one help.I have a input field validation and this field only accepts the number including decimal value also using Angular.js pattern.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">
          Unit Sale Price :
    </span>
    <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.usp.$touched && billdata.usp.$invalid }">
        <input type="text" name="usp" id="usp" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Add Unit Sale Price" 
                ng-model="unit_sale_price" 
                ng-keypress="clearField('usp');" 
                ng-keyup="setLatestSalePrice();" 
                ng-pattern="/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.usp.$error"
     ng-if="billdata.usp.$touched || billdata.usp.$error.pattern">
    <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">
       This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9).
     </p>
</div>
```

Here my problem is the decimal like value are also not taken by this field.Here i need only characters are also not allowed.Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried type="number" to your input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [input[type="number"]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) for this issue:

```
<input type="number" name="usp" id="usp" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Unit Sale Price" ng-model="unit_sale_price" ng-keypress="clearField('usp');" ng-keyup="setLatestSalePrice();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use the regex for this :

```
<input type="text" name="usp" id="usp" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Unit Sale Price" ng-model="unit_sale_price" ng-keypress="clearField('usp');" ng-keyup="setLatestSalePrice();" ng-pattern = "^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$">
```

And use the below expression for error

```
 ng-show="regForm.password.$error.pattern"
```

Comment: its also taking charcter..Please check this.

Comment: @satya I have updated regex, try this.  You can validate this regex on http://www.regextester.com/ .  If still not fix, let me know.